# Window dimensions of the wxt terminal in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to set the size of a wxt terminal window using gnuplot v4.2

```
gnuplot> set terminal wxt size 600,600 
Terminal type set to 'wxt'
     undefined variable: size
```

Even more frustrating is that wxt does not respect the `-geometry` flag like the x11 terminal. Note: I've tried `600,800` and `600x800` both don't work.

```
% gnuplot --version
gnuplot 4.2 patchlevel 4
```

Comment: Silly this got closed, but that seems to be the SO way these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to close this out, I've come to the sad conclusion that gnuplot 4.2 has no size options for the wxt terminal. It will work just as Martin shows for newer versions.

Comment: Just had same problem. I hate Stack Overflow's sometimes absurd question close policies. I guess yours was closed simply because it wasn't in the form of a question.

Comment: It is rather annoying.  I'm glad we both can laugh about our esoteric issues with gnuplot 4.2 and the wxt terminal at least ;)

Answer (score 7):

I think there is a small mistake in your command, you should use , not x, so:

```
set terminal wxt size 600,600
```

Comment: Sorry, this still doesn't work. I tried both. Does it work on yours?

Comment: gnuplot> set terminal wxt size 100,100 gives: Terminal type set to 'wxt' Options are '0 size 100, 100', so it works for me.

Comment: Exactly the same output as Martin got on ubuntu box (10.10) - gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 0

Comment: perhaps it's missing in 4.2? That's rather annoying...